# VBS - Sendkeys with curly braces

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I am trying to level up the Dragon Speech Recognition which uses VBS in its Advanced Scripting Section. Using `SendKeys` behaves strange though. I'd like to send curly braces:

```
SendKeys "{}}"
```

throws an error, while

```
SendKeys "^%0"
```

works flawlessly. Even `SendKeys "{{}"` works but the closing curly brace is only accomplished via `Shift`  + `Alt` + `0`.

The [**documentation clearly states**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.7.2) `{{}` and `{}}` respectively but this won't work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: That is **not** the VBScript documentation, plus `SendKeys` is part of the Windows Scripting Host object model. See the [the WScript Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/8c6yea83(v=vs.84)).

Comment: Have you tested `SendKeys "{}}"` in a simple VBScript outside of Dragon, to isolate whether the script is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445654/vbs-sendkeys-with-curly-braces/67467905#comment119249770_67445654), you need to test this outside the confines of Dragon Speech Recognition. I say this because, with a simple test, it's clear [`SendKeys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/8c6yea83(v=vs.84)) behaves as expected.

```vb
Dim shell: Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call shell.Run("notepad")
Call WScript.Sleep(100)
Call shell.AppActivate("Notepad")
Call shell.SendKeys("{{}")
Call WScript.Sleep(100)
Call shell.SendKeys("{}}")
```

Output (in Notepad):

```
{}
```